# Unity+ARToolKit: rendering error in windows application

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit, 3d-rendering

I use the Unity 5.6.0f3 (Personal Edition) + ARToolkit (v5.3.2) under Windows 10 Home SL. I choose the PC,Mac,Linux option from build settings. I load the default example scene from ARToolkit package (Examples->Scenes->FisticuffsScene) and launch it. I have got that [render problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yau8L.jpg)

Why do some of the model parts not be rendered? Can anyone help me?

**In case of build settings for android everything is rendered fine.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code in a question.

Comment: @Toby Thanks! In this case i didn't write the code. I use default example from ARToolkit and default settings for Unity. I changed marker in ARToolkit object (on scene, in ARMarker script where Marker tag: scientist): i choose **marker type**:  Square and **Pattern file: hiro.patt**